# Is there a way to get my output organized by unique user ID?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a massive dataset (practice Instacart data) I'm working on in Python pandas. I'm trying to create customer profiles, but have just realized that the set includes over 32 million rows(which are unique orders), but ONLY 206,000 unique customers.

```
user_id = [1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6]
department = [produce, pets, frozen, pets, pets, meat, other, pets, snacks, snacks]
order_id = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
income = [72000, 61888, 72000, 72000, 42867, 85629, 85629, 61888, 57211, 53665]

     user_id department order_id income
0    1       produce    1        72000
1    2       pets       1        61888
2    1       frozen     2        72000
3    1       pets       3        72000 
4    5       pets       1        42867
5    3       meat       1        85629
6    3       other      2        85629
7    2       pets       2        61888
8    4       snacks     1        57211
9    6       snacks     1        53665
```

For example, I'd like to create a profile for pet owners by looking for entries that indicate 'pet' in the department column. The issue is that when I count the number of 'pet' entries in the 'department' column, I get 4. The reality is that there are only 3 different users that bought things for pets, not 4.

In order to create an accurate customer profile, I need to be able to know how many unique users shopped in different departments whereas the dataset as it is counts instances.
My apologies if this is not clear, it's my first post for help!

I started with this:

```
df.loc[df['department'] == 'pets', 'pet_owner'] = 'Yes'
df.loc[df['department'] != 'pets', 'pet_owner'] = 'No'
```

Then I realized the analysis issue with just looking at how many ORDERS included pet items, rather than how many unique customers made an order including pet items.

Then I tried this, which was recommended by another user:

```
owns_pets = list(df[df["department"] == 'pets']['user_id'].unique())

no_pets = list(df[df["department"] != 'pets']['user_id'].unique())    

owns_pets.value_counts(dropna = False)

Out: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

So I changed tactics again and tried the following:

```
df.groupby('user_id').agg({'pet_owner' : 'count'})

Out: user_id  pet_owner
        
      1            59
      10           143
      100          27
      1000         103
      10000        1092
      ...          ...
      99995        50
      99996        128
      99997        36
```

Clearly the count is returning each instance rather than just the result 'per' unique user_id.

Can anyone please help me figure out how to get the info the way in which I need? TIA

Comment: What do you mean by you need to run a value_counts() function with the result.  What does the result look like?  Provide an example!

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully be more clear! Thank you!

Comment: You still haven't told us what you desire as the end result.  What is it you want to count?  The number of orders by each user, The number of users who order from pet department, the total value of orders from users who order from pet department or what?

Comment: I apologize, I thought it was clear! As mentioned above, I am looking for the number of unique 'users' that ordered from the pet department, not how many 'orders' include an item from the pet department. Thank you!

Comment: If all you need is the number of unique users who ordered from the pet department why can't you simply take the length of the list provided by my answer below?

Comment: You are correct that that would work, and here comes my screwup in trying to articulate what I need! I created flag columns for the full set and wanted to be able to filter all results by unique user_id in order to perform further analysis and create visualizations. I'm sorry for being so unclear and I did find a solution. Thank you for your time and efforts!

Answer (score 1):

While it is difficult to be sure of exactly what you want, since you haven't provided any sample data nor provided a good example of the desired output.  Here is an approach to select the unique Cust_ID's that have made purchases involving the Pet department.

Given a dF of the following form:

```
    Cust_ID Purch_Date  Dept
0   4817    2022-05-26  Pets
1   3013    2022-01-12  Pets
2   3013    2022-12-22  Hardware
3   4550    2022-04-21  Pets
4   4817    2022-12-26  Hardware
```

You can get a list of the unique cust_id's as follows:

```
list(df[df["Dept"] == 'Pets']['Cust_ID'].unique())
```

This will produce a list of just the cust_ids satisfying the condition that Dept contains 'Pets' as shown below:]

```
[4817, 3013, 4550]
```

If all you need is the number of unique users, just take your answer as:

```
len(list(df[df["Dept"] == 'Pets']['Cust_ID'].unique()))
```

Which in my sample case yields 3

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the response. I'm sorry I'm not familiar with what I need to post. Your suggestion worked to produce a list. I realized that what I need is to be able to run value_counts() on the result and apparently I can't do that with an 'object'. I will try to provide a clearer question and some sample data! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for being unclear with my question. I did end up getting it answered on another forum though and here is the solution:

```
df10exuser = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['user_id'])
```

Comment: The proposed solution simply gives the records from the original df for each unique 'user_id' regardless of whether the user ordered from the pets department.  This is not the the question you asked.  Please in future be careful about clearly asking for a solution.